# Showing error: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js, express

I just started learning express and made a basic server in index.js file with the following code:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server is running on port ${port}'));
```

in the terminal, I wrote "Node index" which should run but it throws error showing 'Cannot find module 'express''

[reference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtwkY.png)

I was expecting it give an output as "Server is running on port 5000"

Comment: `npm install express`